# Get data from Firebase to Ionic(Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

[image]

home.html

```html
<ion-list >
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of itemData | async">{{itemData.$value}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

home.ts

```js
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

itemData: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fbd: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.itemData = this.fbd.list('Arduino/Range1');
  }
```

I would like to data in the red box from to show in Ionic, What should I do?

==============================

Now I can use the data values And I have more questions.

I want to put data in position 1 to a variable value in position 2, what do I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to bind the properties

```
<ion-list >
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of itemData | async">{{itemData.Range1}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: <ion-list >
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of itemData | async">{{item.$value}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vXxt.png

But I want to just one data.

Comment: I recommend that you use the Code results will follow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTsGm.png